# print variable outside function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var userChoice;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rock").click(function(){
  userChoice = "rock";
});
$("#paper").click(function(){
    userChoice = "paper";
});
$("#scissors").click(function(){
    userChoice = "scissors";
});
});
document.write(userChoice);
```

I am trying to get the user output after the click event. But when I run this code I get the output as "undefined". I am very new to programming.

Comment: It's 2017 - `document.write` belongs to a previous millennium, let alone century.

Comment: you're right @Jamiec, but we are talking with a really big newbie!

Comment: @misterwolf even more reason to kill bad habits early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `document.write`. It's considered very bad practice. Instead amend the text of a DOM element to show the output.

Secondly, the problem is because you only check the value of `userChoice` on load of the page. You need to instead check it under each of the `click` events, like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rock").click(function() {
    var userChoice = "rock";
    $('#output').text(userChoice);
  });
  
  $("#paper").click(function() {
    var userChoice = "paper";
    $('#output').text(userChoice);
  });
  
  $("#scissors").click(function() {
    var userChoice = "scissors";
    $('#output').text(userChoice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="rock">Rock</button>
<button id="paper">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Note however that you can improve this code further by using the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. To do that apply a class to all the elements and use a single event handler:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".choice").click(function() {
    userChoice = this.id;
    $('#output').text(userChoice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="rock" class="choice">Rock</button>
<button id="paper" class="choice">Paper</button>
<button id="scissors" class="choice">Scissors</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Ah... Beat me to it

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: Btw! I am using font awesome icons for the rock, paper, and scissors. And they already have a class. How do I use another class with it?

Answer (score 1):

This is because,

```
document.write(userChoice);
```

executes on page load and `userChoice` gets the new value when some `click` action performs.

So try this:

```
$("#scissors").click(function(){
    userChoice = "scissors";
    console.log(userChoice);
});
```

**Note:** Do not use `document.write()` as this will make your entire page blank and show only text in `userChoice`

Comment: Oh yes! But how do I print the new value outside the function. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put printing inside click event.
When page loads, `document.write` fires immediately and its null at that time.

```
var userChoice;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rock").click(function(){
  userChoice = "rock";
  console.log(userChoice);//THIS WAY
});
$("#paper").click(function(){
    userChoice = "paper";
});
$("#scissors").click(function(){
    userChoice = "scissors";
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `document.write()` inside the click callback functions:

```
var userChoice;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#rock").click(function(){
  userChoice = "rock";
  document.write(userChoice);
});
$("#paper").click(function(){
    userChoice = "paper";
    document.write(userChoice);
});
$("#scissors").click(function(){
    userChoice = "scissors";
    document.write(userChoice);
});
});
```

`document.write()` gets called once the page has loaded and only this time. But as you didn't give `userChoice` a value on initialization, it's value is `undefined`. When you click on one of the buttons, the value of `userChoice` gets changed, but `document.write()` gets not called again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your functions by only one and get the choice by using `innerHTML` or change it where the value is.

Your `document.write(userChoice);` will be executed before the click events and will not be updated on click

```js
var userChoice;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".choice").click(function(){
    userChoice = this.innerHTML;
    console.log(userChoice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="choice">rock</p>
<p class="choice">paper</p>
<p class="choice">scissors</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. never execute document.write after page load. Instead update some tag's .html()
2. you execute your write before you click anything.

You likely mean

```js
var userChoice = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hitme").click(function() {
    userChoice = this.id;
    $("#choice").html(userChoice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="hitme" type="button" id="rock">Rock</button>
<button class="hitme" type="button" id="paper">Paper</button>
<button class="hitme" type="button" id="scissors">Scissors</button>
<span id="choice"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, better do not give you the final code but more explanation about code execution:

Do not use

```
document.write
```

it's dangerous, it can rewrite whole html page (when the page is already loaded).

The output is set on "undefined" because the variable

```
userChoice
```

is not still initialized, it will be initialized once user triggers an event: in your case a click on the divs. So just move the "userChoice" print/elaboration

```
 (eg: $('.some_div').innerHTML = userChoice)
```

into an eventHandler, like one of yours:

```
$("#scissors").click(function(){ .... })
```

Read this guide for better info about javascript execution/running time: http://davidshariff.com/blog/what-is-the-execution-context-in-javascript/.
If you will like it and coding in general maybe in future you will post other interesting questions about Javascript!